# Is the worst time complexity of BFS in a graph traversal n+2E?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

I  understand that time complexity of BFS in a graph traversal is `O( V + E )` since every vertex and every edge will be explored in the worst case.

Well,is the exact time complexity `v+2E` ??

Every vertex is explored once+ Every adjacent vertices

The sum of the degree of all the vertices in a `graph= No of edges*2= 2E`

Thus the time complexity is `n+2E`..Am i correct?

Comment: The sum of the degrees of the vertices is twice the number of edges.

Comment: `O(V+E)` is equivalent to `O(V+2E)`, since `V+2E <= 2*(V+E)` and `O(2*(V+E))` is equivalent to  `O(V+E)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a random graph, the time complexity is `O(V+E)`: [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

As stated in the link, according to the topology of your graph, `O(E)` may vary from `O(V)` (if your graph is acyclic) to `O(V^2)` (if all vertices are connected with each other).

Therefore the time complexity varies from`O(V + V) = O(V)` to `O(V + V^2) = O(V^2)` according to the topology of your graph.

Besides, since `|V| <= 2 |E|`, then `O(3E) = O(E)` is also correct, but the bound is looser.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

Let's assume that G is connected and undirected. If it's not connected, then you can apply the below idea to every connected component of G independently. In addition, let's assume that G is represented as an adjacency lists and for every vertex v, we can decide if v was visited in O(1) time for example using a lookup table.

### Analyze

If you want to count the exact number of steps in the BFS you can observe that:

1. Since G is connected, BFS will visit every vertex exactly once, so we count |V| visits in nodes. Notice that in one visit you may perform more operations, not counting looping over edges, than just marking current vertex visited.
2. For every vertex v we want to count, how many edges the BFS examines at this vertex.

You have to loop over all edges of v to perform the BFS. If you skip one edge, then it's easy to show that BFS is not correct. So every edge is examined twice.

One question may arise here. Someone could ask, if there is a need to examine the edge (p, v) in vertex v, where p is the parent of v in already constructed BFS tree, i.e. we came to v directly from p. Of course you don't have to consider this edge, but deciding to skip this edge also costs at least one additional operation:

```
for (v, u) in v.edges:
    if u == p: # p is the parent of v in already constructed tree
        continue
    if not visited[u]:
        BFS(u, parent=v)
```

It examines the same number of edges that the code below, but has higher complexity, because for all but one edge, we run two if-statements rather than one.

```
for (v, u) in v.edges:
    if not visited[u]: # if p is the parent of v, then p is already visited
        BFS(u, parent=v)
```

### Conclusion

You may even develop a different method to skip edge (v, p), but it always takes at least one operation, so it's a wasteful effort.