# Big O with 2 variables which multiply together

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, computer-science

If I take the function:

```
def nested_multiplier(a, b):
    """
    returns a*b
    """
    count = 0
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            count += 1
    return count
```

It is fairly clear here that the complexity in terms of number of asignments is going to be a * b.

Fine so far so good.

So if I want to work out the Big O in terms of a I guess I have to consider that the function has O(n) because I must consider b as a constant value in this case?

And equally if I want the big O in terms of b it would be O(n) for the same reasons.

This seems to make sense but intuitively with a nested iteration block like this I expect an O(n^2), or some other exponential type value. And this makes perfect sense when you consider a and b in terms of having the same value (i.e. let a = 5 and let b = 5 there will be 25 assignments).

So what is the correct way to express the complexity of this function in Big O notation?

Comment: This question is more suitable for computer science stack exchange but I have also answered .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two variables inside the O(n) notation. For example this [graph complexity question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615362/is-the-worst-time-complexity-of-bfs-in-a-graph-traversal-n2e) uses both the number of vertices and edges for complexity analysis. In your case the answer will be O(a*b), or if you want it more n-like,  you can use O(n*m).

Assuming b or a as a constant to use only one variable in O(n) notation is misleading for analysis. Always use every input that affects complexity.

Answer (score 1):

`Big O` is a function of how you measure input size. If you measure it as e.g. `n = |a| + |b|` or `n = max(|a|,|b|)` then the complexity is `O(n^2)`, which is the most reasonable way to express it in terms of a single parameter. On the other hand, you could simply leave it as `O(a*b)`. Saying that it is `O(a)` or `O(b)` is misleading unless you intend to fix one or the other of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, essentially it's exactly as you've said it yourself:

If one of your parameters `a` or `b` is going to be a **constant** then the time complexity is going to be `O(b)` or `O(a)`, because it doesn't depend on the constant factor.

If however, both `a` and `b` can be arbitrarily big then the asypmtotic time complexity (`a -> inf` and `b -> inf`) will be O(a * b).

The essential point is that Big O notation describes **asymptotic** complexities, so while it can be a little confusing thinking about the runtime for small `a` and `b` intuitively for when one of them is a constant, when you let the other value grow towards infinity, the linear runtimes make sense again.